# What does colon mean in function definition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was thinking that colons can only work in object literals. 
But when I ran the following code, browser didn't give me any error.
And I also can't figure out what does the colon do in the function.

Here is my code:

```
var testFn = () => {
    abc: 1;
}

testFn();
```

Can you tell me what does this code do?

Comment: Look up labels.

Comment: to answer your question "what does this code do", as written, that `testFn` does absolutely nothing, and results in a return value of `undefined` - whereas the author probably meant `var testFn = () => ({
    abc: 1;
});` which will return an Object `{abc:1}`

Comment: @JaromandaX: That's a syntax error, as object literal doesn't suffer a semicolon. (Nitpick though; I believe your impression of the author's intent is correct.)

Comment: @JaromandaX , I guess that the topicstarter produce normal code with label. Please look here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to remove the moved ; in what I presumed the authors intent was. I do know about labels but label makes even less sense in that code

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for your heads up. I have read through MDN docs about label. It mentioned that labeled function is available in non-strict mode. But when I try to use it in chome 67, error says: Undefined label 'block1' .I am not sure if I code in wrong way or chrome does not support it. Do you have an example for this?

Comment: There is no code in your question that invokes a label, and there is no label `block1`. Also, that looks like an unrelated question; if so, please submit is as such. If it is still related to this question, please add enough detail so we can see it, and be able to answer.